# MVC Core, How to retrieve the index of one of the List object

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am sorry for being unclear. Here's my code which I hope explain more

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Test(int classid)
    {

        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
<form asp-action="Test">

    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
        {
            var buttonid = "btnSubmit" + i;

        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model[i].Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model[i].ClassName)
        <input name="submit" id="@buttonid" type="button" data-classid="@Model[i].ClassID" value="Go to class Form" class="btn btn-default MyButtonClass" style="font-size: 14px" />

    }
<script>

    $(document).on("click", ".MyButtonClass", function () {

        var id = $(this).data("classid");
        alert(id);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/StudentController/Test",
            data: { classid: id }
        });

    });

</script>
</form>
```

So what I wanted to do is when the user click the submit, it will redirect to another form which contain the className information (I know how to redirect to another page), however, the problem is that in another controller, I could only retrieve List and not the selected index className. Is there any method to retrieve the index when the user click submit?

Thanks

Comment: if you wrap your controls in a form and post it, you can post to which ever controller/Action you wish too.

Comment: @Wheels73 Hi, thanks for the answer. Yes it is being wrapped in a form, the problem is that the entire List<Students> is being sent to the Controller, I have no idea under which index the submit button was clicked

Comment: You are getting the entire list because your submit button is inside the form and the default action for a submit is to post the entire form, despite your ajax function which is trying to post just one id.  You will need to `preventDefault` or similar to prevent this.  Often I actually use anchors instead of buttons, they look the same (because of bootstrap) but are easier to override.

Comment: @nurdyguy Thanks for the reply, how do you use anchor instead of buttons though? Like anchor is used for posting link, how do you actually use it?

Comment: Yes, anchors are normally used for links, but with bootstrap styling you can make an anchor look just like a normal button.  Try this `<a class="btn btn-default MyButtonClass" data-classid="@Model[i].ClassID" id="@buttonid">Go to class Form</a>`

Comment: @nurdyguy Yeah, nice. Thanks for the help. But it's still not working :<. the anchor cant be clicked at all.

Comment: What do you mean "cant be clicked at all"?  if you put a breakpoint in your binding, it should happen when you click on the anchor.  Also, move the `<script></script>` to outside of the form.  Also, why are you using a form?  If you just want to do an ajax post then you don't need the form tags at all.

Comment: @nurdyguy Thanks for the response, Yeah it really can't be clicked at all. Missing the href? It just became like a text, the css is working on the otherhand

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a form?

Comment: @nurdyguy I have removed the form actually

Comment: Ok, since you removed the form tags then convert the anchors to buttons `<button ... >`.  The anchor tag trick is something I use (not everyone does) to prevent default behavior of forms, but isn't necessary if you killed the form tags.  Make them buttons though, not inputs.

Comment: @nurdyguy Thanks a lot but I still have the same result, the page won't refresh, the debugging not working it just seems like nothing happen. :(

Comment: Oh, I meant to mention this before...  ALWAYS wrap your js bindings inside of `$(document).ready(function(){  .........  });`  Once it was no longer a form submit the js was dead because of the load order.  Put your binding inside of that and it should clear that up.

Comment: @nurdyguy I am really sorry! but it's still not working. I wrapped it already inside starting from  $(document).on("click", ".MyButtonClass", function () { until the end inside the ready(function). But the result still the same

Comment: Sounds like something is broken somewhere.  I posted an answer, try that and we'll see what we can come up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put an answer below which should hopefuly help you on your way.

First of all, build you your list of students in your controller.

```
 public class TestController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Test()
        {

            var list = new List<Student>()
            {
                new Student()
                {
                    Name = "Student1",
                    ClassID = 1,
                    ClassName = "ClassA"
                },
                new Student()
                {
                    Name = "Student2",
                    ClassID = 2,
                    ClassName = "ClassB"
                },
                new Student()
                {
                Name = "Student3",
                ClassID =3,
                ClassName = "ClassC"
                }
            };

            //You can call a service and populate your own data.

            return View("Test", list);
        }
    }
```

Specify the views model

```
@model List<TestMVC.Student>
```

Then loop through each student, generating a unique id for each button and putting the classid (what ever key id you need) into the data-classid attribute.

```
  @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        var buttonid = "btnSubmit" + i;

        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model[i].Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model[i].ClassName)
        <input name="submit" id="@buttonid" type="button" data-classid="@Model[i].ClassID" value="Go to class Form" class="btn btn-default MyButtonClass" style="font-size: 14px" />
        <br/>
    }
```

We also specify a new css class called "MyButton". This will serve the jquery selector.

```
<style>

    .MyButtonClass {
        color:red;
    }

</style>
```

Then use Jquery to capture the button clicked, take off the id and post id as a parameter to which ever controller and action you want.

```
<script>

    $(document).on("click", ".MyButtonClass", function () {

        var id = $(this).data("classid");
        alert(id);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/YourController/YourAction",
            data: {classid:id}
        });

    });

</script>
```

The line for "data". The "classid" must be the same name as the parameter on your controller. So the posted actions signature would be

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void YourAction (int classid)
    {

    }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hello,Thanks for your help. I tried to debug and check whether the classId works or not however, when I click on the button, nothing happens, I just edited my post with your code in it, mind help me look at it ? Thanks a lot really appreciate it..

Comment: Morning, I can see others have been helping... did you get it sorted?

Comment: @Wheels74 Hi wheels, thanks for your answer. yes and no do you have any solution? Thanks

Comment: I've noticed that you've put your script in the middle of the form. Move the script block to the very bottom of your page. It should come after </html>. Try it with the Developer tools window open as well and see if there are any errors. Also, try removing the asp-action tag. We are posting via ajax now and so its not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div id="classList">

    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        var buttonid = "btnSubmit" + i;

        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model[i].Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model[i].ClassName)
        <button id="@buttonid" data-classid="@Model[i].ClassID" class="btn btn-default MyButtonClass">Go to class Form</butotn>

     }
</div>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(".MyButtonClass").on("click", function () 
        {

            var id = $(this).data("classid");
            console.log(id);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/StudentController/Test",
                data: { classid: id },
                success: function(data)
                {
                    // put redirect in here
                    window.location = .....;
                },
                error: function()
                {
                    // error handling
                }
            });

         });
    });//------- this was missing!!!!
</script>
```

In your controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Test(int classid)
{
    // put debugger here so we know if we landed
    return new { success=true};
}
```

You are using an ajax post so you probably just want data returned, not an entire view.  Or do you?  What exactly is supposed to happen when you get here?

Comment: Thanks a lot, just tried this, I delete the window.location part hope its okay, i dont have any place I want to redirect it to. I put the debugger there and it just won't land :( I just want to see the classId being retrieved there and that's all. I am working on another project file which is too large to share but same concept.

Comment: Do I need to install anything on my NuGet or something? or attach any scripts there before the Ajax/Json thingy?

Comment: in your browser, open the networks tab and tell me what shows up when you click the button.

Comment: You need jQuery but if you don't have that loading on the page then you'll see a big red error in the console "$ is not defined...".

Comment: I opened the console it had error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input". The networks tab when I clicked the button nothing shows up. But when loaded it has "Test" document there

Comment: the MVC Core come with the jQuery script document and bootstrap so I think should be fine

Comment: Ok, on the line where the error shows up, to the far right it should have what looks like a link, click it and see what shows up.  It should take you to where the syntax error is.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but now got new error "Test:22 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" which is $(document).ready(function(), any idea what might be the prob?

Comment: @Krayon2  Is the entire purpose here that if they click the button then it load the new page based on which button they clicked?  If so then i could simplify this a whole lot...

Comment: Yes, " $ is not defined..." means that jQuery is not loaded on the page.  It is in your project but not being loaded on that page.  Look in Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml and see if it has a line that says `<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>`

Comment: My bad, yes it is in there. I modified the Layout already and make it into Shared/_Layout, but the error is still the same $ is not defined

Comment: I added the jQuery directly into the page, but now I had this problem "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()" Any idea what might be the probleM/

Comment: Play with the src reference that I posted, make sure that is where it is in your project.---- Look in wwwroot/lib and see where your jquery is.

Comment: Yup it is inside, It is loaded now

Comment: Just that now I had this problem "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()" Any idea what might be the probleM/

Comment: Look on the networks tab and see which line has a 404 next to it.  That will tell you which resource it can't find.

Comment: umm, It's from the Test, "Test 404 xhr jquery.js:9172"

Comment: Replace the line in _Layout.cshtml with this one `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`  That is google's hosted jQuery.  This will help us narrow down the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164198/discussion-between-nurdyguy-and-krayon2).